# Use user credentials to login to facebook using javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using Javascript sdk with a facebook app to create login page for user. 
FB.login prompts the user to enter facebook username and password. I have saved all the info such as user_id, Access_token, and all info. However, when the user logout. I want to login to facebook without the need to re-enter username and password again. i want to use the user-id and access token to login directly using the javascript API.

Thanks

```
   function updateButton(response) {
                button       =   document.getElementById('fb-auth');
                userInfo     =   document.getElementById('user-info');

                testbut     =   document.getElementById('test');

                var rr = getResponse("user_profile.xml");

                if(rr != null)
                    {
                response = rr;
                    }
                if (response.authResponse) {alert('me/permissions/?access_token='+     


      response.authResponse.accessToken);
    FB.api('me/permissions/?access_token='+ response.authResponse.accessToken    

          ,function(response)


    {
  for (var name in response) {
               alert(response.data);
           }
        alert(response);

  });

                    //user is connected
                    FB.api('/me', function(info) {

                        login(response, info);


                    });

                    button.onclick = function() {
                        FB.logout(function(response) {
                            logout(response);
                        });
                    };
                } else {
                    //user is not connected

                    button.innerHTML = 'Login';
                    button.onclick = function() {

                        FB.login(function(response) {
                            if (response.authResponse) {
                                FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                                    login(response, info);

                                });
                            } else {
                                //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                                showLoader(false);
                            }
                        },  

    {scope:'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_about_me'});
                    }
                }
            }


            // run for the current status and whenerve it is changed
            FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);
        };

        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol
                + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());


        function login(response, info){
            if (response.authResponse) {

                ajaxFunction(response);
                var accessToken =   response.authResponse.accessToken;

                userInfo.innerHTML  = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + info.id  
                                  + "<br /> Your Access Token: " + accessToken;
                button.innerHTML  = 'Logout';
                document.getElementById('other').style.display = "block";


            }
        }

        function logout(response){
            userInfo.innerHTML  =   "";
            document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = "";
             document.getElementById('other').style.display = "none";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store User access token in your database to user for next time.
Here is some small hint to pass access token using javascript sdk

```
FB.api('me/permissions/?access_token=Your access token',function(response){console.log(response)});
```

Comment: thanks. Actually i saved it. I have access token and userid. But how to use them to auto login without the need from user to enter username and password after logging out.

Comment: you have to send the stored access token when requesting to the facebook using javascript sdk.

Comment: I am still getting undefined for the response object.

Comment: try passing the access token every where you call "FB.api".

Comment: thanks very much but actually still getting undefined for that. probably because i am logged out. The token is not valid anymore. i want to be able to go the wall by that

Comment: and this is the error
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 467
   }
}

Comment: hmmm... try removing you cache and try again.

Comment: Still the token is not valid

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in a bit late, but my guess is you are trying to login using an expired or invalidated short-term access token.  For future logins, you should convert the short-term access token to a long-term access token, good for about 60 days.  The conversion to a long-term token needs to happen on your server as it requires your app-secret.  Details are [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending).  The long-term token is what you should be storing in your database (or similar) for future use.